# beginner questions about class and objects

Tags: c++

I'm working on a small program for school that is an intro to using objects.  I'm new to class and still trying to wrap my head around it.  I'm not really asking how to fix my code, I'm just looking to get a better understanding of things.

In the code below, in my implementation file student.cpp, there is a function called `isLessThanByID`.  It is supposed to compare the current object to the object being passed in.  I'm having a hard time understanding what the "current" object is and how the function knows what the current object is.  There are two objects s1 and s2.  My instructor says assume s1 is the current object and s2 is the passed in object.  I asked my instructor how the function knows about s1 if it's not being passed in and she said it's because s1 is an object of class and the function is a class member.  This made sense for a minute and then I thought on it more and realized I'm still confused.  If s1 doesn't need to be passed in, then why does s2 need to be passed in?

I'm getting an error on that function that says

> "error: extra qualification ‘Student::’ on member ‘isLessThanByID’ [-fpermissive] bool Student::isLessThanByID(const Student &s2) const;".

I'm not sure what it means by "extra qualification".

I really appreciate any help in wrapping my head around this! Thank you!

Here's my code:

app.cpp

```
const double minGpaForHonor = 3.75;

int main()
{
        Student s1("G10", 3.9);
        Student s2("G20", 3.5);


        s1.print();
        s2.print();

        //write code to test Student::isLessThanByID
        s1.isLessThanByID(s2);

        if (true)
                 cout << "s2 is less than s1" << endl;

        else
                cout << "s1 is less than s2" << endl;

    //write code to test Student::qualifyForHonor
    s1.qualifyForHonor(minGpaForHonor);
        if (true)
            cout << "s1 qualifies for honors" << endl;

    s2.qualifyForHonor(minGpaForHonor);
        if (true)
            cout << "s2 qualifies for honors" << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

student.cpp - implementation file

```
//implement the required 3 functions here

Student::Student(const char initId[], double gpa)
{
        //initialize ID
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(initId); i++)
        {
        id[i] = initId[i];
    }

        gpa = gpa;
        //initialize gpa
}

bool Student::isLessThanByID(const Student &s2) const
{
        //compare current student object to passed in object}
        if (strcmp(s1.id, s2.id) < 0)
                return true;

        else
                return false;

}

bool Student::qualifyForHonor(double minGpaForHonor) const
{
//return true if gpa is higher than "minGpaForHonor"
        if(gpa >= minGpaForHonor)
                return true;
}
void Student::print() const
{
  cout << id << '\t' << gpa << endl;
}
```

student.h- header file

```
#define STUDENT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
        Student(const char initId[], double gpa);
        bool Student::isLessThanByID(const Student &s2) const;
        bool qualifyForHonor(double minGpaForHonor) const;
        void print()const;
private:
        const static int MAX_CHAR = 100;
        char    id[MAX_CHAR];
        double  gpa;

};
#endif
```

Comment: `if (true) do_something` will always `do_something`, because `true` is always true. I think you need to study a little more about functions. And make sure that your functions that promise to return a value always do.

Comment: ... just remove `Student::` from function definition in .h

Comment: Either your instructor has no idea about how things work, or you have misunderstood each other.

Comment: I'm sure I must have misunderstood her.

Answer (score 1):

> *How the function knows about `s1` if it's not being passed in?*

Each member function has an implicit (hidden) first parameter that passes a **pointer to the "current" object** (available inside that function as `this`). Imagine that

```
bool Student::isLessThanByID(const Student &s2) const
{
   return strcmp( /* s1. */ id, s2.id) < 0;
}
```

is actually something like

```
bool Student::isLessThanByID(const Student* this, const Student &s2) // not real code
{
   return strcmp(this->id, s2.id);
}
```

Similarly, imagine that the call

```
s1.isLessThanByID(s2);
```

is actually

```
Student::isLessThanByID(&s1, s2); // not real code
```

Note that there is no `s1` inside `isLessThanByID` available. That object exist outside of the function definition, so, you cannot use it inside. Instead of `s1.id` just write `this->id`, or, shortly, just `id` (which will be interpreted as `this->id` implicitly in your case).

Comment: Thank you, thank you, for the thoughtful response.  I'm still stuck, though.  We haven't learned about this-> yet, so I'm not allowed to use it.  Would the other answer be to just pass in both objects?

Comment: @newGirl You don't need `this` at all. I just tried to illustrate how things work with member functions — `s1` is actually passed in via implicit `this` parameter, `s2` needs to be passed by an explicit parameter. Therefore, yes, both objects need to be passed in, but both in a different way.